# How do you ask for permission in android?

Tags: android, security

Can someone tell me where in the docs it goes over how to ask for permissions to access the file system or other media?

If an app doesn't ask for permission during installation, this means it does not have permissions to ask for any data other than its own isolated storage space?

Comment: not sure what can be said that you could not find in the documentation in more comprehensive and precise terms. Unless you have a specific issue?

Answer (score 2):

### Permissions

**If you're using Android 5.1 or lower** all the permissions your app requires have to be declared on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. As you can see [on the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

**Example:**

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
   ...
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application ...>
       ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

If you didn't declare a permission on your manifest file, it was impossible to request a new one after installation, unless you updated your app requestion new permissions.

**But that changed on Android 6.0 (API Level 23)**, where you can request permissions at runtime.

From the docs:

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This
>   approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not
>   need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also
>   gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example,
>   a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not
>   to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any
>   time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

So instead of asking for all permissions on app install:

[image]

Starting from Android 6.0, permissions can also be requested like this:

[image: Taken from the docs.]

For more information, [check the training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) or [this link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en).

### File access

If you want to have write access the external file storage, you have to declare a permission for that, as it's stated [on the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

> To write to the external storage, you must request the
>   `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest file.

**Example:**

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

And if you just want to read it, all apps already have that ability, but it might change in the future, so it's better to use this permission instead:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every thing you need to know about system permissions is located here in the documentation :

[Working with System permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html)

Starting at API 23 (Marshmallow), the system will not ask permission at install time but at runtime when the developer thinks the permission is needed.

Comment: While this does answer the question, Mauker's answer is more complete and should be the accepted answer.